# Getting results based on first query

Tags: mysql

I am newbie in mysql.Suppose you have a database table named 'table1':

```
id  cityA   cityB   producer
_____________________________
1   Rome    Berlin    Alan
2   Vienna  Hanover   Max
3   Rome    Berlin    Peter
4   London  Siena     John
```

First,i want to get the row where producer is Alan:

```
$query = "
SELECT cityA , cityB , producer
FROM table1
WHERE table1.producer = 'Alan' 
";
```

that returns row id =1.
How can i get now all rows that have same cityA,cityB as row 1 at the same php script, i mean not using second ajax call;

Expecting result:

```
    1   Rome    Berlin    Alan   
    3   Rome    Berlin    Peter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
join
(
  SELECT cityA, cityB
  FROM table1
  WHERE producer = 'Alan'
) t2 on t1.cityA = t2.cityA and t1.cityB = t2.cityB
```

Comment: Sorry juergen but what do you mean by 'select t1.*'. Everything in table1;

Comment: Yes, everything in `table1`. `t1` is the alias for `table1`. You could change the FROM clause like this `from table1 AS t1` instead to make it more clear.